# xlCellTypeLastCell giving incorect value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulty getting an accurate value from `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` in Excel VBA. The following code should output the row number for the first empty row in the "TrackedItems" worksheet. The worksheet has 8 lines, but the code outputs 25 (should output 9):

```
emptyRow = 1 + wb.Worksheets("TrackedItems").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
MsgBox emptyRow
```

In this particular instance, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957994/select-first-empty-cell-in-column-f-starting-from-row-1-without-using-offset) will solve my problem, because the spreadsheet is not sparsely populated (there are no blank cells mixed in with non-blank cells). However, I have used `xlCellTypeLastCell` many times, and not encountered this problem, including in situations where data *is* sparseley populated. What causes `xlCellTypeLastCell` to behave in this manner? Is there any way to make it behave properly, or must I rely on custom-coded functions? Should I replace my older work using `xlCellTypeLastCell` with such functions, or does the fact that it currently works mean that it won't break later (at least if I do not change any code in those workbooks)?

Comment: Can you provide some example data as sounds like the issue may be related to the data structure in your worksheet.

Comment: it doesn't need to be so difficult if you search first empty row in certain column. Or as @Ripster stated above- knowing data structure could help to provide some simple and alternative solutions...

Comment: BTW, according to MSDN: **"xlCellTypeLastCell. The last cell in the used range"** which means 'Used Range of whole sheet, not referenced range'. Moreover, it happens that cells which seems to be empty is not. Some cell's informations are kept which makes the problem of yours.

Comment: I would provide data, except the problem has now magically fixed itself. If it starts up again, I will be sure to edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
emptyRow = range("A" & activesheet.rows.count).end(xlup).row
```

to return the last row with data in it maybe?

Comment: Thanks: this code had been working perfectly for at least three years and this morning broke: lLastRow = Range("A1").SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 
    
I have replaced with lLastRow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row and now the macro works as expected again

Answer (score 0):

There was probably formatting in row 24.  I know I'm a dab late, but I just had this problem.

xlCellTypeLastCell will give the last cell with formatting, even if it's empty.

You may want this, adapted from http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

```
Sub Lastcell(rowz&, colz&) ' -- get last cell in sheet
  Dim zRange As Range
  Set zRange = Cells.Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False)
  If zRange Is Nothing Then rowz = 1 Else rowz = zRange.row
  Set zRange = Cells.Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False)
  If zRange Is Nothing Then colz = 1 Else colz = zRange.Column
End Sub
```