# Excel.Application.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) returning bottom of worksheet, not last data cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I'm writing a method in VBA in Excel 2013 to loop through the rows in two worksheets and compare the text in a column from each. When I run my code, I find that the code loops through the entire worksheet, not just the rows with data.

`Excel.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` returns a cell in the correct column, but the row is the last row in the sheet (1048576), rather than the last row with data (1951).

I had written a check for empty cells (since I can't be sure that every row in the valid range is used), so it doesn't cause any errors, but as this method is called from inside `Worksheet_Change`, it really slows things down.

Normally when the "last" cell is reported incorrectly a save usually fixes it, and if that doesn't, then deleting the rows (not just the contents, but the entire rows) from the mis-reported last cell back to the actual last cell and *then* saving works. However, in this instance, it is not helping.

I searched with Google without success. I'd like to not have to copy all the data and code out of this workbook and into a new one. Any ideas?

Comment: Finding the last row is a cornerstone of VBA programming. Here is, what I would consider at least, the definitive write-up on finding the last row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Thanks for the info; see my comment on Christopher's answer below.

Also, any idea why this was downvoted? This isn't a duplicate of that question; my question is how to fix xlCellTypeLastCell, not how to do it with a workaround? And if this got downvoted, why didn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090426/xlcelltypelastcell-giving-incorect-value) that asked the same question, with a "it magically fixed itself, I'll post back if it happens again" resolution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(Too much info to use a comment here.)

VBA mastermind Ron de Bruin wrote a little snipped about why `xlCellTypeLastCell` as well as `UsedRange` might be failing here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm.

(In the post I linked to in my initial comment, [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba), the pitfalls of `UsedRange` are described in the same way.)

Here's the direct quote:

> Possible problems with xlCellTypeLastCell and UsedRange are:
>
> The last cell will only re-set when you save (or save/close/reopen the
>   file). If cell formatting is changed it will not reset the last cell,
>   clearing the data is not enough, you must delete the rows or columns
>   then,  See: http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqApp.html#Unused

To make a long story short, the logic for finding the last row on a sheet belongs inside a global function. You will use this function all the time. Here's an example for finding the last row on a sheet:

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
'EXAMPLES    :
' 
'assume that there is a single 
'entry on MySheet in cell A5:
'
'LastRowNum(MySheet)
'>> 5
'
'assume that EmptySheet is totally empty:
'
'LastRowNum(EmptySheet)
'>> 1
'
Public Function LastRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRowNum = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Else
        LastRowNum = 1
    End If
End Function
```

As far as the downvote goes -- no idea. I've actually never downvoted here haha.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the additional info. So not just UsedRange, but xlCellTypeLastCell should be avoided as well as a best practice, from the sounds of things (this post, the linked post, and other posts that searches about this have led to). I guess I just have to accept that xlCellTypeLastCell is to be removed from my toolbox. :-P And I wasn't asking you specifically about the downvote; Stack Exchange doesn't tell you who downvoted, so I have NFI who I should ask. I was just hoping whomever did it would see the comment and respond.

Comment: It's the middle of 2016 now.  Should `xlCellTypeLastCell` still be considered broken?  If so, does MS consider this a bug?

Comment: As far as I can tell yes, it still only updates when the workbook saves. MS might not consider it broken but if they don't its most certainly misleading and infact a little useless so should still be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code to determine the last row & column instead

```
Dim LastCol As Long

Dim LastRow As Long

LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But why doesn't xlCellTypeLastCell work? I would have thought that that would be a cleaner and preferred method; does it just not work? I've never had a problem with it before?

Comment: That's a quick and dirty way; the _dirty_ part being that, for example, if your last cell in column A is in row 150, but you have a value in cell E200, then it's going to **exclude 50 rows** that it should not. I suppose if you always have a header and a left row that extends at least as far as the data does, it will work, but that's assuming a level of cleanliness that's _very_ hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Dim xlastcel As Range  
On Error Resume Next  
   ActiveSheet.ShowAllData: Err.Clear  ' Show All  
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange               ' Ajust Vertical Scrool  
   With ActiveSheet:  Set xlastcell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious): End With  
   If Err.Number > 0 Then MsgBox "Sheet without data", vbOKOnly  
On Error GoTo 0
```