# How do I use xlCellTypeLastCell in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I selected all cells in a sheet and Clear All to bring me a blank spreadsheet. Then I entered in E6 and A1 some texts. Then I ran the following code, however, I got E7 cell selected. How weird! I wonder if I missed something.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: See [Excel.Application.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) returning bottom of worksheet, not last data cell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25110873/4088852).

Answer (score 2):

Call the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) all by itself to reset the [xlCellTypeLastCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) of the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx).

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("E7") = "abc"
    Cells.Clear
    Range("E5") = "xyz"
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
End Sub
```

If you step through that with [F8], first E7 will be selected, then after the call to .UsedRange, E5 will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience the best solution to finding last cell / row etc. containing data is by .find method, because it is reliable even after deleting some data. The only drawback is that it doesn't detect hidden rows.

Code below returns the last row containing data in 5th column (Column E). Replace "Columns(5)" with "Cells" if you want to get number of last row containing data in your whole sheet.

Selecting is a bad practice in VBA (slow - can't use for big data sets and non transparent for coding). You can refer to the cell from my code as Range("E" & TheLastRow).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
Dim TheLastRow as long
  TheLastRow = Columns(5).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably best to include an `After:=Cells(1, 5)` as a parameter to that [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx). I don't hink you would want to rely on whatever is the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx).