# check for value , compare and copy to another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with two columns. Column (E) contains ID and names from the data source and column (K) contains ID,which are extracted from comment section.

Column E contains sometime ID, starting with B2C, and sometime names and Id starting with 5. column K contains always ID starting with B2C.   the length of the ID B2C is usually 11 to 13 Digit Long. the length of ID starting with 5 is 8 Digit Long.

I would like to have a VBA that checks both the columns, if there is an id starting with 5 or some Name in column E,  then it should look into column K, if an ID starting with B2C is present, then it should copy to Column L, else copy the same value(from column E) to column L.

I researched through find and replace. I saw examples where exact Name of find was given and replaced with given Name. I am able to form an algorithm, but struck how to start with code in my case.  the code below, has an runn time error

> object varaible or with block variable not set .

```
Sub compare()

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet


ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

For i = 1 To Rows.Count

If ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then

ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value

Else

ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I have an Image below, which Shows the end result.[image: the result should be generated as shown in image]

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this have to be VBA? Could *easily* be achieved with a cell formula...

Comment: ya, want to have  it with  VBA.

Comment: Okay... you say "If it's a 5xxx ID or a name, look into column K" but your example on the first line has copied from K regardless. Should the value from K be taken as long as it's not blank?

Comment: @Mikz - cool the question is understandable, what have you done so far?

Comment: @Vityata ,I tried a code, in such a way that if column k is empty, then it copies the value of column e to L, else it copies column k value to L. I am completely new to VBA. i have an idea, but not able to form it as code thats why i posted the question without code.

Comment: @Wolfie , it is  because, they both are same value,  thats why it has been copied from K. Sometime there are Chance that a 0 in column e is less than column k but, they both are same value.

Comment: @Mikz - can you post your code in the question?

Comment: ya,i will post the code.but there is an run time error, Object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: You ned to use `Set` for non-core variable types (string/integer/etc): `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: @Mikz - cool, its ok that's why we are here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue causing the error message is that you are missing a `Set` statement for your worksheet object. You must use `Set` when assigning an object to a variable, that is anything with its own methods. A simple data type without methods (`String`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Boolean`, ...) doesn't need the `Set` statement, and can just be directly assigned like `i = 0`.

Your code should be updated to:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
' RED FLAG! Rows.Count is going to cause you to loop through the entire column,
' see the below example for how to use the UsedRange property.
For i = 1 To Rows.Count 
    If ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
        ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
    Else
        ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value
    End If
Next I
```

---

An alternative which avoids even using a worksheet variable would be to use a `With` block:

```
Dim r As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For r = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        .Range("L" & r).Value = .Range("E" & r).Value
        If .Range("K" & r).Value = "" Then .Range("L" & r).Value = .Range("K" & r).Value
    Next r
End With
```

---

**Edit**:
There are various ways to find the last used row, each with their drawbacks. A drawback of *both* `UsedRange` and `xlCellTypeLastCell` is they are only reset when you save/close/re-open the workbook. A better solution can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25126427/3978545).

```
Sub compare()
    Dim r As Long, lastrow As Long, ws As WorkSheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = LastRowNum(ws)
    With ws
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            .Range("L" & r).Value = .Range("E" & r).Value
            If .Range("K" & r).Value = "" Then .Range("L" & r).Value = .Range("K" & r).Value
        Next r
    End With   
End Sub

' Function from linked question
Public Function LastRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    LastRowNum = 1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRowNum = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It Works fine :)

Comment: The usage of `.UsedRange.Rows.Count` to define the last row is really a bad solution and you should not be even thinking about doing it. It works ocassionally, only if you start the worksheet from the first row.

Comment: The OP clearly is starting the worksheet from the first row, since they were looping from row 1 in their example code, and since their headings are there it will always contain data... Saying it "works occasionally" implies it doesn't give predictable behaviour, but it is a [well defined method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) of the worksheet which works consistently. I have updated my answer accordingly anyway for the sake of being pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim lngLastRow      As Long
    Dim ws              As Worksheet

    lngLastRow = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    With ws
        .Columns(12).Clear
        .Cells(1, 12) = "Extract from Comment"
        For i = 1 To lngLastRow
            If .Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
                .Cells(i, 12).Value = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
            Else
                .Cells(i, 12).Value = ws.Cells(i, 11).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

It clears column(12) and writes *Extract from comment* in the first cell of the row, to make sure that everything is clean. 
`lngLastRow` is the last row of the sheet.

Comment: Clearing the column does nothing when every value is over-written anyway?

Comment: @Wolfie - indeed, but if you are debugging it helps you see better what is happening. Because if you run it twice and then debug, the old values would stay.