# How to set a range while executing Worksheet.Cells.Replace

Tags: excel, vba

Have been trying to run Replace function, it generally works, but take so much time to execute, I have a bunch of workbook files, near to 40, and each file have two sheets I need to replace values in.
Basically the VBA performs translation by replacing one string with another from a array.
I thought maybe by limiting the execution of the VBA to a range could help?

Here is the part of the code I run for described above purpose:

```
'Create variable to point to your table (reference to the table for replace values
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LangLibGT").ListObjects("LangTable2")

'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
  Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
  myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
  
'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
  fndList = 1
  rplcList = 2

'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Sheet2 " Then

            'Loop through each item in Array lists
              For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)

            ws.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
              LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
              SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
              On Error Resume Next

              Next x
              
        End If
```

The Above mentioned code has been updated to the following one suggested by @InjuredCoder:

```
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LangLib").ListObjects("LangTable")
                                            
                                            'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
                                              Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
                                                    myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
                                              
                                            ' Make into dictionary - with help from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-range-to-dictionary.1075087/
                                            Dim MyDict As Object, i As Long, MyVals As Variant
                                        
                                            Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                                            
                                            For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
                                                MyDict(myArray(i, 1)) = myArray(i, 3)
                                            Next i
                                        
                                            'Dim ws As Worksheet
                                            'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
                                        
                                        'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
                                            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                                                If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Sheet2 " Then
                                                    ' set up the array to work through
                                                    Dim myTargetArray As Variant, rngTo As Range
                                                    colNum = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
                                                    rowNum = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                                                    Set rngTo = ws.Cells(rowNum, colNum)
                                                
                                                    myTargetArray = ws.Range("A1", rngTo).Formula
                                                
                                                    For i = 1 To UBound(myTargetArray)
                                                        For j = 1 To UBound(myTargetArray, 2)
                                                            If myTargetArray(i, j) <> "" Then
                                                                If MyDict.Exists(myTargetArray(i, j)) Then
                                                                    myTargetArray(i, j) = MyDict(myTargetArray(i, j))
                                                                End If
                                                            End If
                                                        Next j
                                                    Next i
                                                    ws.Range("A1", rngTo).Formula = myTargetArray
                                                End If
                                            Next ws
```

Comment: so what you appear to be doing here is looking through every cell to see if it equals myArray(1,1) then every cell for myArray(1,2) etc.  Basically every time you have to interact with Cells excel takes time.  doing it lots of times is going to really slow this done.  Are the tables tables of values or do they have formula in?  I think you should consider copying the data into an array affecting the array and then copying it back out, it will likely be by far the quickest run time

Comment: in answer to your immediate question though try `rg.Cells.Replace...` where rg comes from your new code and that new code is placed just after your `If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Sheet2 " Then` line

Comment: Thanks for your reply @InjuredCoding, right, the code does exactly that, unfortunately there are a bunch of cells with formulas on both sheets as well, so pulling and putting cells values back can't be used unless there is a parameter that would skip proceeding the function on cells with formulas. I have merged the given above code the way I asked and you helped to figure it out, and generally it works, but seems like it did not increase efficiency (reduce time of execution). Need to consider other way of dealing with this part then.

Comment: @InjuredCoding, do you think it would be possible to do something like VLookUp formula does, but with VBA for the array while skipping cells with formulas and maybe also ? I have tried running the code, and it takes just so much time to execute, 2-4 minutes per workbook.

Comment: you must have asked this while I was coding the below - have a go with that and let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you need, it will maintain formulas and only change values where the whole value of the cell is in the lookup you have.

It converts your input table to a dictionary and your whole sheet to an array on the formula level and then applies the dictionary to each cell.

I think this should be the most efficient way of doing it

```
Sub ditionary()
    'Create variable to point to your table (reference to the table for replace values
      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LangLibGT").ListObjects("LangTable2")
    
    'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
      Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
      
    ' Make into dictionary - with help from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-range-to-dictionary.1075087/
    Dim MyDict As Object, i As Long, MyVals As Variant

    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(TempArray)
        MyDict(TempArray(i, 1)) = TempArray(i, 2)
    Next i

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Sheet2 " Then
            ' set up the array to work through
            Dim myTargetArray As Variant, rngTo As Range
            colNum = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
            rowNum = LastRowNum(ws)
            Set rngTo = ws.Cells(rowNum, colNum)
        
            myTargetArray = ws.Range("A1", rngTo).Formula
        
            For i = 1 To UBound(myTargetArray)
                For j = 1 To UBound(myTargetArray, 2)
                    If myTargetArray(i, j) <> "" Then
                        If MyDict.Exists(myTargetArray(i, j)) Then
                            myTargetArray(i, j) = MyDict(myTargetArray(i, j))
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
            ws.Range("A1", rngTo).Formula = myTargetArray
        End If
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Note:  you will also need this function that is a wholesale copy of the excellent answer by @DanWagner [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110873/excel-application-cells-specialcellsxlcelltypelastcell-returning-bottom-of-wor)

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
'EXAMPLES    :
'
'assume that there is a single
'entry on MySheet in cell A5:
'
'LastRowNum(MySheet)
'>> 5
'
'assume that EmptySheet is totally empty:
'
'LastRowNum(EmptySheet)
'>> 1
'
Public Function LastRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRowNum = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Else
        LastRowNum = 1
    End If
End Function
```

this reduces interaction with your worksheet to two calls and the array is only searched once.  this should result in a large step in efficiency (hopefully!)

Comment: Thank yo a lot for helping me out, I have tried the solution, but confused for the line being muted:
    'MyVals = Range("A2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

and the debugger returns "Type mismatch" error on the following line. I have tried un-muting it, but still do not proceed. Any idea what can be the problem? I added the Function above as a module.

Comment: hey, do you mean the commented out line?  I think that was only there from the original I used to make this.  Have now deleted, does it work now?

Comment: That line apparently did not make much sense since it was muted, but I added a line :
myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)  , without it the debugger had been giving error of type mismatch. But now I faced the next challenge, the Public function give an error by saying that : Unable to get the CountA property of the WorksheetFunction class.

Comment: I have two WB open while running the code above, so the code that is being discussed here is located in one WB, and the the actions being done on another WB. therefore, in watchdog I see that LastRowNum Function runs on another sheet, can I specify the WS I need?

Comment: try replacing `rowNum = LastRowNum(ws)` with `rowNum = ws.Range("A"& rows.count).end(xlup).row` and see how it runs.  the problem with this method is that if column A is not the longest row in the sheet it wont do all the data.  but first lets see if that solves the problems

Comment: on the Transpose point i had assumed the reference table to be in columns i.e. `A1:B500` is that not the case?

Comment: I change the line to the mentioned, it passed that part, but somehow stuck at ws.Range("A1", rngTo).Select, saying  " Select method of Range class failed" .

Regarding the table, it is actually wider, depending on the file content, I have given that range as an example

Comment: ok, sorry must have been late or something when I wrote this, got rid of that line, it's not needed

Comment: Thank you, removed the line, it proceeds without interruption, but do not replace values. Checked watch window for the myTargetArray, seems like all non formula values are being "" and other are my formula values.

Comment: going to add another answer to work through this and then delete that answer once we have it all working for you

Comment: I have updated the first topic starting question to the vba that proceeds but does not execute what is needed yet

Answer (score 0):

so I can't replicate the issue

if you try these two codes (hoping I can code this early in the morning!) hopefully it will show where the issue for the main code comes in:

remember to change the variables at the top

```
Sub copyPaste2()

    ' rename to the sheet where your stuff is
    SheetFrom = "Sheet1"
    ' add a sheet and change this to that sheet name
    SheetTo = "Sheet2"
    ' change this range to cover your data
    RangeStr = "D15:D22"
    
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetFrom)

    'Create variable to point to your table (reference to the table for replace values
      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LangLibGT").ListObjects("LangTable2")
    
    'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
      Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
      
    ' Make into dictionary - with help from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-range-to-dictionary.1075087/
    Dim MyDict As Object, i As Long, MyVals As Variant

    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(TempArray)
        MyDict(TempArray(i, 1)) = TempArray(i, 2)
    Next i
    
    
    myArray = ws.Range(RangeStr).Formula
    
    Sheets(SheetTo).Range(RangeStr).Formula = myArray
    
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub copyPaste3()

    ' rename to the sheet where your stuff is
    SheetFrom = "Sheet1"
    ' add a sheet and change this to that sheet name
    SheetTo = "Sheet2"
    ' change this range to cover your data
    RangeStr = "D15:D22"
    
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetFrom)

    'Create variable to point to your table (reference to the table for replace values
      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LangLibGT").ListObjects("LangTable2")
    
    'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
      Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
      
    ' Make into dictionary - with help from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-range-to-dictionary.1075087/
    Dim MyDict As Object, i As Long, MyVals As Variant

    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(TempArray)
        MyDict(TempArray(1, i)) = TempArray(2, i)
    Next i
    
    
    myArray = ws.Range(RangeStr).Formula
    
    ' change the values for the dictionary value
    For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        For j = 1 To UBound(myArray, 2)
            If myArray(i, j) <> "" Then
                If MyDict.Exists(myArray(i, j)) Then
                    myArray(i, j) = MyDict(myArray(i, j))
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Sheets(SheetTo).Range(RangeStr).Formula = myArray
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this one, it works, it copies values to another sheet while keeping the formulas

Comment: have edited this with two other codes - the original code works for me and the fact the other one works for you makes it hard to replicate the error.  but i think if we build the code up like this hopefully we will see where the error is coming in

Comment: Thank you^^ Im to apply the the code, meanwhile what I have realized, that the code inserts the same string that it has pulled, so replacement is happening, but with the original. I understood this by seeing some cell with reference to empty cell start indication 0 ( they originally hold ' values to eliminate 0 return values). Any idea what it is this way?

Comment: sorry not sure i follow, do you mean that empty cells are now showing with a 0 in them?  I'm struggling a little as the code isn't doing any of this on my computer.  the copy paste just copies and pastes everything as it was.

Comment: Both codes from yesterday return a error at the same part, saying Type mismatch after the line 'For i = 1 To UBound(TempArray)'. This time I run the code in a new wb without any extra code., so seems like there is something to do with TemaArray type?

Comment: Sorry for late feedback, had been out of my laptop for a week for a business trip.

Comment: I have tried to run both of code option on a different machine, with a simple file and data sets, and it returns the same error, 'Type mismatch after the line 'For i = 1 To UBound(TempArray)'. Not sure where is the problem, but seems like the approach isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

If try to declare the line below then the vba proceeds (without Type Mismatch error), but then just copies values from source sheet to another sheet

> myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

Sub copyPaste3()

```
    ' rename to the sheet where your stuff is
    SheetFrom = "LGEHVAC"
    ' add a sheet and change this to that sheet name
    SheetTo = "Sheet2"
    ' change this range to cover your data
    RangeStr = "B4:N62"
    
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetFrom)

    'Create variable to point to your table (reference to the table for replace values
      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LangLib").ListObjects("LangTable")
    
    'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
      Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
      
      myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
      
      
    ' Make into dictionary - with help from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-range-to-dictionary.1075087/
    Dim MyDict As Object, i As Long, MyVals As Variant

    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        MyDict(myArray(i, 1)) = myArray(i, 2)
    Next i
    
    
    myArray = ws.Range(RangeStr).Formula
    
    ' change the values for the dictionary value
    For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        For j = 1 To UBound(myArray, 2)
            If myArray(i, j) <> "" Then
                If MyDict.Exists(myArray(i, j)) Then
                    myArray(i, j) = MyDict(myArray(i, j))
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Sheets(SheetTo).Range(RangeStr).Formula = myArray
    
End Sub
```

Comment: this edit wont work as you've reused myArray.  your underlying table being two rows instead of two columns is doing my head in!  i've edited `copyPaste3()` in my other answer to deal with that it should now copy the sheet1 table to sheet2 and change the words that are in your dictionary lookup.  its here that i think the same problem may occur as in the original code.  like i say i'm not seeing that behavious so its hard to get to the root of it