# Delete a column based on whether the dynamic range in that column is blank or has formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete columns based on whether the cells in a specific range in that column are blank or contain formulas. It needs to be dynamic as the number of rows can change.

I've got an image to highlight what type of data I'm working with. The cells highlighted in yellow are in the columns i want to delete.

[image: data types]

```
Sub deleteColumns()

Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = lastColumn To 6 Step -1
    If Range(Cells(3, i) & Cells(lastRow, i)) = 0 Then
        Columns(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This is the code i have so far but i just can't get the logic to work as i am new to VBA.

If anyone could help me out i'd greatly appreciate it

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please read: [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110873/excel-application-cells-specialcellsxlcelltypelastcell-returning-bottom-of-wor) about your use of xlCellTypeLastCell. As for your requirements, what if one (or more) of the cells has something else than a formula in it(/them)?

Comment: You cant use Range with more cells in a condition. Use this: `range(cells(1,1),cells(1,3)).specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count=range(Cells(1,1),cells(1,3)).Count`

Comment: @Notus_Panda The columns which contain the formulas also have column headings but nothing else.

Comment: @Blackcat thanks for the speedy response but where do i write that?

Comment: I'm talking about columns that have both formulas and non-formula filed cells (header not-included), they remain?

Comment: @Notus_Panda There are not columns that have both formulas and non-formula filled cells. Either formula filled or blank or filled and i want to get rid of formula filled and blanks.

Comment: In the If statement adapted like this: `If range(cells(3,i),cells(lastrow,i)).specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count=range(Cells(3,i),cells(lastrow,i)).Count Then`

Comment: @Blackcat I tried it the way you mentioned in the earlier post but unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: This expression throws an error if specialCells doesn't find any cell in the range. You have to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to count the special cells trapped in a `On Error Resume Next ... On Error GoTo 0` (since specialcells throw an error when there aren't any) but I figured there should be something way easier and **there is!**

```
Sub test1()
    Dim lCol As Long, i As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim sRow As Long: sRow = 2 'modify this start row as needed
    Dim sCol As Long: sCol = 1 'modify as needed
    With ActiveSheet
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lRow = Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'change if need be to a filled-col
        Dim rng As Range
        For i = lCol To sCol Step -1
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(sRow, i), .Cells(lRow, i))
            If rng.HasFormula Or Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
                Columns(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Let me know if something is unclear or doesn't work in your use-case.

Comment: Thank you, that worked immediately! It got rid of the formula and blank columns. - Many many thanks. Just as a follow up, in the future if i need to scan a dynamic range i should create a rng parameter?

Comment: Depends what your goal is but it can't hurt creating a range variable to work around with. They're quite versatile and then you know you'll always have that range (unless you set it to something else of course). Don't forget to also define which worksheet(s) you're working with so your vba doesn't need to guess (usually goes to Activesheet).

Comment: Oh okay, thanks again i wish i had a follow up but i believe i understand what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

With this modification using the SpecialCells method and eliminating the no cells found error message:

```
Sub deleteColumns()

Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = lastColumn To 6 Step -1
    On Error Resume Next
    If Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(lastRow, i)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count = _
    Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(lastRow, i)).Count Then
        If Err = 0 Then Columns(i).Delete
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It also works as well but doesn't remove columns filled with formulas, but i could add that code. Follow up question, what is the logic stating in english?

Comment: @guswo Yes, you can extend the if statement with `Or Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(lastRow, i)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Count = Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(lastRow, i)).Count` which will delete in any of the two cases is fulfilled. The logic is that compare the BlankCells or the FormulaCells count in a range to the total number of cells in that range, and if they are equal then delete the column.