# Execution macor excel (1004) vba

Tags: vba, excel, button

When I try to run the following macro through a button that I drew on my workbook I get the an error (1004). The macro looks like this:

```
Sub copy_data()
' Copy incident_id and ticket_id from raw_incidents
    Sheets("Raw_Incidents").Select
    Range("Raw_incident[[id]:[ticket_id]]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Report").Select
    Range("Report[[incident_id]:[ticket_id]]").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

' Copy ticket_id from raw_old_ticket_support
    Sheets("Raw_Old_Support_Tickets").Select
    Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Report").Select

' Function found on this page:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957994/select-first-empty-cell-in-column-f-starting-from-row-1-without-using-offset
    Range("A8:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Range(Selection.Cells(1, 2), Selection.Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveSheet.Range("Report[#Tout]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

The error is on the last line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Report[#Tout]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
```

However when I run the macro from the editor, so by pressing the run button, it works fine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: If you change to this: `Sheets("Report").Range("Report[#Tout]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes`  does the error still happen?

Comment: I did this and yea i still have the error

Comment: Is the worksheet protected?

Comment: Or, on which worksheet exists the `Range("Report[#Tout]")` ?  (I assume it was on Sheets("Report")

Comment: yea it is, its a table on the sheet called Report, what is strange is that when i run the code from the editor it work but when i run it with the button it bugs.

Comment: Any help ? i still have the issue... i tried the following:   Sheets("Report").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("Report[#Tout]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
    Range("A7").Select