# Get the number of next empty rows

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get the number of the next empty rows, calculated from a declared cell : 
As you can see this is the problem : 
[image: get N° 7 declared cell is "A4"]

I do this but I don't get the correct response : 
[image: VBA Code1]

```
Sub sup_rapp1()
'*variables
Dim CELDEB As Range, LIGNEFIN As Long, COLONEFIN As Long, WS As Worksheet
'set objet : affecter les objets
Set WS = Sheets("TAB1")
Set CELDEB = Range("A4")
'derniere ligne at colonne of data
LIGNEFIN = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, CELDEB.Column).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox LIGNEFIN
```

[image: wronge reponse Code 1]

[image: Code2]

```
Sub sup_rapp1()
'*variables
Dim CELDEB As Range, LIGNEFIN As Long, COLONEFIN As Long, WS As Worksheet
'set objet : affecter les objets
Set WS = Sheets("TAB1")
Set CELDEB = Range("A4")
'derniere ligne at colonne of data
LIGNEFIN = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, CELDEB.Column).End(xlDown).Row
MsgBox LIGNEFIN
```

[image: wrong reponse code 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first empty cell in column F starting from row 1. (without using offset )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957994/select-first-empty-cell-in-column-f-starting-from-row-1-without-using-offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Set WS = Sheets("TAB1")
Set CELDEB = WS.Range("A4")

LIGNEFIN = CELDEB.CurrentRegion.Row + CELDEB.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

MsgBox CStr(LIGNEFIN)
```

The `CurrentRegion` gives you the boundaries of the region your cell is in.

The reason you did not get the correct result with your code was that you selected the last row on the sheet and then went up, which gave you `11` or when down (that is you stayed on the last row) which gave you the other value.

Comment: thank you it's work correctly ; i didn't understand the last row of your code : "CStr ("LIGNEFIN"). ?

Comment: @H.hisoka, CSTR is nothing but conversion of value to string