# Excel - Adding a row outside of forumla range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vba

Currently I have a couple of SUM functions setup in my worksheet.

Lets use H2:H34 for my example: If I add a row within that range, the sum function will automatically adjust. The problem is when I add new rows, it is below the range (below H:33). In this case, I would just have to highlight the column and expand/drag the range to where it needs to be. There are a total of 8 columns that are doing a sum function. Is this only possible by using a macro?

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,H2:H34)
```

Comment: Is `=SUBTOTAL(3,H:H)` not an option?

Comment: That was the first option I tried but it turns the total to "0". The sum formula sits in a H cell as well (H:35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your formula being the extent of the range minus one row we can use this:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,H2:INDEX(H:H,ROW()-1))
```

Now as rows are added or deleted the reference will remain intact.

If there is a chance that row 2 would be deleted you will get #Ref errors.  To avoid that you can use this formula:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,INDEX(H:H,2):INDEX(H:H,ROW()-1))
```

Now there are no specific cell references and adding or deleting will not effect the formula and the range will be dynamic.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Golden. This solved my problem.Ty! Good to see there is a resolution outside of macros.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a named range like =sum(range1) and something like;

[Select first empty cell in column F starting from row 1. (without using offset )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957994/select-first-empty-cell-in-column-f-starting-from-row-1-without-using-offset)

to find the first empty cell to change the reference for the named range.

Triggering it would be difficult... potentially could use on_save?

or option 2.... bit of a dodge, but can work....

you say your sum is in cell H35... maybe move it to h36, and create a dummy hidden row in 35 (0.1 row height). that way when you add a row, it is always above 35. Use sum H1:H35 and it will always auto update? its not a neat solution, but should work

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code, you need to adjust column "H" to whatever column you need.

```
Dim sumtest    As Variant

sumstest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("H2:H" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row))
```

Comment: As an OT: Integer is deprecated, you may google Integer vs Long to see why, just change Integer to Long

Comment: I would change it to a Double instead, as both Integer and Long will remove the decimal, if there are any.