# Excel VBA Code to search range of cells to see if it contains a space

Tags: excel, vba

I have search high and low, but I am after a vba code to search a range, ie A1:A1000, and if it finds a cell that contains a space, then to pop up with a message box.

Thanks

Comment: Googling "excel vba find blank cells": [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14962028/1726522). Googling "excel vba message box": [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx). Just join  both.

Answer (score 0):

How about..

```
Set r = Range("A1:A1000").Find(What:=" ", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
If r Is Nothing Then
' code to run if nothing found
Else
 MsgBox "Space found in cell " & r.Address
End If
```

**EDIT** - removed the `After:` parameter as this caused issues when cell beyond search area was active.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example:

```
Dim cell As Range

Set cell = Range("A1:A1000").Find(What:=" ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    Stop 'do something
Else
    Stop 'do something else
End If
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx