# When I copy and paste into 2 different Excel workbooks with powershell it messes up

Tags: excel, powershell, copy, paste

I have 2 Workbooks, I am trying to copy a range B2:B5000 from Report1 and paste it into Column A of Report2. It does copy and paste however the past goes into Report2 Column H20.. How can I specify what range to paste into? Here is what I have so far

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.Visible = $true
$SrcWkBk =$Excel.Workbooks.open("C:\Reports\Report1.xls")
$TRgWkBk =$Excel.Workbooks.open("C:\Reports\Report2.xlsx")
$SrcWkBk.WorkSheets.item(1).activate()
$SrcRng=$SrcWkBk.WorkSheets.item(1).range("B2","B5000");
$SrcRng.copy() | out-null;
$TRgWkBk.worksheets.item(1).paste();
```

Comment: Have you defined the top left cell for the paste range?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before the line where you paste the results:

```
$TRgWkBk.worksheets.item(1).range("A1").Select
```

You need to select the cell before pasting in the contents.

And, consider taking off the semi-colons. You only use them if you're putting more than one command on the same line, and you're not doing that here.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Any idea how to paste to the first blank cell in a specific column?

Comment: Adapt the VBA from the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957994/select-first-empty-cell-in-column-f-starting-from-row-1-without-using-offset and reference the answer from CameronFace.