# How can I place a formula in the first empty cell on Column F?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

How can I place a formula in the first empty cell on Column `F`?

`F3` is empty cell.
Need for that empty cell be `=F2`

Note: I'm looking for code to look for first empty cell `F` and I need to be able to insert in the first empty cell `=F3`.

[image: Sample Data]

Currently working with following code [copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812127/445425)

```
Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

sourceCol = 6   'column F has a value of 6
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
        Exit For 'This is missing...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: When [copying code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812127/445425)   from elsewhere on SO, you are required  to give attribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code implies you want to consider truely Empty cells and cells that contain an empty string (or a formula that returns an empty string) <sup>Note 1</sup>.  (Given you simply copied that code from elsewhere, that may not be the case)

You can use `End(xlDown)` to locate the first truely Empty cell, or `Match` to locate the first "Empty" cell in a range (either just empty string, or either empty strings or Empty cells, in different forms)

If you want to find the first truely Empty cell, *or* cell containing an empty string:

```
Function FindFirstEmptyOrBlankCell(StartingAt As Range) As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set search range
    With StartingAt.Worksheet
        Set rng = .Range(StartingAt, .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartingAt.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
    End With

    ' Find first empty or blank cell
    Set FindFirstEmptyOrBlankCell = rng.Cells(StartingAt.Worksheet.Evaluate("Match(True, " & rng.Address & "=""""" & ", 0)"), 1)
End Function
```

If you want to find the first truely Empty cell, and ignore cells containing an empty string:

```
Function FindFirstEmptyCell(StartingAt As Range) As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set search range
    With StartingAt.Worksheet
        Set rng = .Range(StartingAt, .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartingAt.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
    End With

    ' Find first empty cell
    If IsEmpty(StartingAt.Cells(1, 1)) Then
        Set FindFirstEmptyCell = rng.Cells(1, 1)
    ElseIf IsEmpty(StartingAt.Cells(2, 1)) Then
        Set FindFirstEmptyCell = rng.Cells(2, 1)
    Else
        Set FindFirstEmptyCell = rng.End(xlDown).Cells(2, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

And for completeness, if you want to find the fisrt cell containing an empty string, and ignore truely Empty cells:

```
Function FindFirstBlankCell(StartingAt As Range) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim idx As Variant
    'Set search range
    With StartingAt.Worksheet
        Set rng = .Range(StartingAt, .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartingAt.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
    End With

    ' Find first blank cell
    idx = Application.Match(vbNullString, rng, 0)
    If IsError(idx) Then
        'There are no Blank cells in the range. Add to end instead
        Set FindFirstBlankCell = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 1)
    Else
        Set FindFirstBlankCell = rng.Cells(idx, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

In all cases, call like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet '<~~~ or specify required sheet
    Set r = FindFirstEmptyOrBlankCell(ws.Range("F3"))

    ' literally what was asked for
    'r.Formula = "=F3"

    ' possibly what was actually wanted
    r.Formula = "=" & r.Offset(-1, 0).Address(0, 0)

End Sub
```

---

<sub>Note 1
`If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then` is actually redundant. Any value that returns TRUE for `IsEmpty(currentRowValue)` will *also* return TRUE of `currentRowValue = ""` (The reverse does not apply)</sub>

From comment *can that same Fuction repeat until the last empty cel?* I think this is what you mean is to continue to fill blank cells down through the used range

If so, try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim r As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet '<~~~ or specify required sheet

    Set cl = ws.Range("F3")
    Do
        Set r = FindFirstEmptyOrBlankCell(cl)
        If r Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        r.Formula = "=" & r.Offset(-1, 0).Address(0, 0)
        Set cl = r.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note, I've modified `FindFirstEmptyOrBlankCell` above to aloow it to return `Nothing`  when it needs to:

```
Function FindFirstEmptyOrBlankCell(StartingAt As Range) As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set search range
    With StartingAt.Worksheet
        Set rng = .Range(StartingAt, .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartingAt.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
    End With

    ' Find first empty or blank cell
    On Error Resume Next ' Allow function to return Nothing
    Set FindFirstEmptyOrBlankCell = rng.Cells(StartingAt.Worksheet.Evaluate("Match(True, " & rng.Address & "=""""" & ", 0)"), 1)
End Function
```

Comment: I apreciate i just started using it, took me a while to understand it and adapting the code into macro but i finally got.

yes, i wanted with following code (r.Formula = "=" & r.Offset(-1, 0).Address(0, 0))

:P

Comment: can that same Fuction repeat until the last empty cel?

Comment: Neilsem thank you! Yes that's what I whanted, currently im teachig my self how to doe this but this falls in more advance codes, currently I'm look for what I need on internet and if I find it i use it on my macros, but if i dont i get a similar code and ask if somenhing like this can get use. I really apreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your `rowCount`, the way you have it, the loop will stop before the first blank row. I believe you should just be able to set use `.Formula` for the empty cell. Hope this helps:

```
Sub EmptyCellFillFormula()

    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 6   'column F has a value of 6
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Formula = "=F3"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```