# Obtain row number of the first blank row in a column Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to obtain the value of the first blank row in a column (such column has ~20k values). For example, the cell E23495 is the last one in column E which has a value in it, a non-blank value, I want the number 23496 which is the row that has the first blank row. I have found a solution but an error appears in such conditions that makes this code unusable, either a solution or other code that does the job will do just fine

I have modified the code of the best answer in this question

[Select first empty cell in column F starting from row 1. (without using offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957994/select-first-empty-cell-in-column-f-starting-from-row-1-without-using-offset)

So I try the next code

```
Sub Main()
    NextFree = Worksheets("Bajada").Range("E2:E" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
    Worksheets("Muestra").Range("O10").Value = NextFree - 1
End Sub
```

Which actually works, but when I add values to the column E in worksheet 'Bajada' it stops working and the next error appears "Run-time error '1004': No cells were found." The idea is to keep on adding values to this column and that this code keeps on searching for the new row that has a blank value.

Comment: Could you please check your post, because you are writing _I am trying to obtain the value of the **first** row in a column_ and then _the **last** one in column_ So, what is it what you are after?

Comment: Edited, thanks, no matter how many times I re read it, there is always something I miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I got you right but to my understanding you would like to get the row number of the first blank row in column E.

Based on the code [here](https://youtu.be/DpwAO5qnvAQ) one could use the following function to achieve that

```
' Description: Finds the last row in a given range or worksheet.
' YouTube video: https://youtu.be/DpwAO5qnvAQ
' ExcelMacroMastery.com
Function FindLastRow(rg As Range) As Long
    
    On Error GoTo eh
    
    FindLastRow = rg.Find("*", , Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
            , searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Exit Function
eh:
   If Err.Number = 91 Then
        MsgBox "No data found for range [" & rg.Address & "]. Last row will be set to first row of range."
    End If
    FindLastRow = rg.Cells(1, 1).Row
End Function
```

And you would just add one, i.e

```
rowNr = FindLastRow(Columns("E"))+1
```

But (there is always a but) the code above will skip blank intermediate rows. It will not find blank rows in between.

**PS**: The code from orignal post could be changed to

```
Sub Main()
    NextFree = FindLastRow(Columns("E"))+1        
    Worksheets("Muestra").Range("O10").Value = NextFree
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this will work, I may be asking too much but I am pretty new in VBA, but could you please edit it to find this last row in column E and paste such value in let's say cell E23497? Thanks

Comment: I edited the answer. Is that what you are aksing for?